# Constraint violation with @OrderColumn in @ManyToMany

Tags: jpa, java-8, many-to-many, eclipselink

I get a violation of a primary key constraint of the join table, that is automatically created by EclipseLink for the following classes:

```
@Entity public class Link {
    @ManyToMany @OrderColumn
    private List<Node> nodes; ...

@Entity public class Node {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "nodes") 
    private List<Link> links; ...
```

The violation occurrs, if I insert a Link with the same Node on first and second position of it's nodes. Indeed there is a generated index with NODES_ID and LINKS_ID (missing NODES_ORDER). How could I influence EclipseLink or other Providers in order to ommit or extend this constraint?

Using: Glassfish 4.1.1, EclipseLink 2.6.4 or 2.7.0 (cross post), Java 8

Comment: and where do you define your join table? Also a small sql with ddl of the tables would be usefull

Comment: With JPA (convention over configuration) I don't need to define it. The join table LINK_NODES is automatically created on startup, but with the above mentioned unwanted constraint.

Comment: This is posssible by setting javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action to create-or-extend-tables in persistence.xml.

Comment: Post the DDL for the join table? where is the SQL that inserts into the join table? Is the list an ordered list or an indexed list?

Comment: EclipseLink doesn't support duplicates in collections.  You can try manually removing the constraint in the generated DDL, and then use scripts from then on, but there may be other problems - be sure to test that it works well enough for you.

Comment: Chris, that's a really valuable information!! I dropped the constraint but then got duplicate Links. So I might have to invent a trick for the standard requirement to allow duplicates in a List (not a Set). Fascinating ...

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=256978 shows that this bug exists since 2008 so I might have to try an other Provider

Comment: JPA does not require duplicates to be supported, and most providers do not. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey( name = "none")
```

on both sides of the mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! As I'm using EclipseLink/JPA there is no Hibernate annotation available. Hovever, there is a deprecated @javax.persistence.ForeignKey annotation since JPA 2.1 that can't be applied there. So, the solution might be something like using \@JoinColumn or \@JoinTable.

Comment: @JoinColumn(foreignKey=@ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)) does not work